# search for regex match between two files using python

Tags: python, regex

I´m working with two text files that look like this:
File 1

```
#   See ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/README_assembly_summary.txt for a description of the columns in this file.
# assembly_accession    bioproject  biosample   wgs_master  refseq_category taxid   species_taxid   organism_name   infraspecific_name  isolate version_status  assembly_level  release_type    genome_rep  seq_rel_date    asm_name    submitter   gbrs_paired_asm paired_asm_comp ftp_path    excluded_from_refseq    relation_to_type_material   asm_not_live_date
GCF_000739415.1 PRJNA224116 SAMN02732406        na  837 837 Porphyromonas gingivalis    strain=HG66     latest  Chromosome  Major   Full    2014/08/14  ASM73941v1  University of Louisville    GCA_000739415.1 identical   https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/739/415/GCF_000739415.1_ASM73941v1         na
GCF_001263815.1 PRJNA224116 SAMN03366764        na  837 837 Porphyromonas gingivalis    strain=A7436        latest  Complete Genome Major   Full    2015/08/11  ASM126381v1 University of Florida   GCA_001263815.1 identical   https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/001/263/815/GCF_001263815.1_ASM126381v1            na
GCF_001297745.1 PRJNA224116 SAMD00040429    BCBV00000000.1  na  837 837 Porphyromonas gingivalis    strain=Ando     latest  Scaffold    Major   Full    2015/09/17  ASM129774v1 Lab. of Plant Genomics and Genetics, Department of Plant Genome Research, Kazusa DNA Research Institute GCA_001297745.1 identical   https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/001/297/745/GCF_001297745.1_ASM129774v1            an
...
```

File 2:

```
#   See ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/README_assembly_summary.txt for a description of the columns in this file.
# assembly_accession    bioproject  biosample   wgs_master  refseq_category taxid   species_taxid   organism_name   infraspecific_name  isolate version_status  assembly_level  release_type    genome_rep  seq_rel_date    asm_name    submitter   gbrs_paired_asm paired_asm_comp ftp_path    excluded_from_refseq    relation_to_type_material   asm_not_live_date
GCA_000739415.1 PRJNA245225 SAMN02732406        na  837 837 Porphyromonas gingivalis    strain=HG66     latest  Chromosome  Major   Full    2014/08/14  ASM73941v1  University of Louisville    GCF_000739415.1 identical   https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/739/415/GCA_000739415.1_ASM73941v1         na
GCA_001263815.1 PRJNA276132 SAMN03366764        na  837 837 Porphyromonas gingivalis    strain=A7436        latest  Complete Genome Major   Full    2015/08/11  ASM126381v1 University of Florida   GCF_001263815.1 identical   https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/263/815/GCA_001263815.1_ASM126381v1            na
```

So, I want to search for a specific pattern using regex.
For example, file 1 has this pattern:

```
GCF_000739415.1
```

and file 2 this one:

```
GCA_000739415.1
```

The difference is the third character: F versus A. However, sometimes numbers differ.
Difference between files is the third row of data.
These two files have a lot of patterns like the previous one, however, there are some differences. My goal is to search for the pattern that only exists in one file and not in the other file.
For example, "GCF_001297745.1 in the third row in the file 1 but not in the file 2. This should be a GCA_001297745.1"

I´m working on a python code:

```
# PART 1: Open and read text file
with open("assembly_summary_genbank.txt", 'r') as f_1:
    contents_1 = f_1.readlines()
with open("assembly_summary_refseq.txt", 'r') as f_2:
    contents_2 = f_2.readlines()

# PART 2: Search for IDs
matches_1 = re.findall("GCF_[0-9]*\.[0-9]", str(contents_1))
matches_2 = re.findall("GCA_[0-9]*\.[0-9]", str(contents_2))

# PART 3: Match between files
# Seudocode
for line in matches_1:
    if matches_1 == matches_2:
        print("PATTERN THAT ONLY EXIST IN ONE FILE")
```

Part 3 refers to doing a for loop that searches for each line in both files and prints the patterns that only exist in one file and not in the other one.
Any idea for doing this for loop?

Comment: What exactly are you matching? is it: `GC[some letter]_[some numbers].`?

Comment: Yes `GC[F or A]_[some numbers]`, the most of these patterns are in both files, so I'm looking for those that are only in one

Comment: Alright, I'll update my regex

Comment: I added more data with an expected result, let me know if you understand my goal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are after this?

```py
import re

given_example = "GCA_000739415.1 PRJNA245225 SAMN02732406        na  837 837 Porphyromonas gingivalis    strain=HG66     latest  Chromosome  Major   Full    2014/08/14  ASM73941v1  University of Louisville    GCF_000739415.1 identical   https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/739/415/GCA_000739415.1_ASM73941v1         an"
altered_example = "GCA_000739415.1 GCTEST_000739415.1"

# GX[A or F]_[number; digit >= 1].[number; digit >= 1]
regex = r"GC[AF]_\d+.\d+"

matches_1 = re.findall(regex, given_example)
matches_2 = re.findall(regex, altered_example)
```

---

```
# Iteration for intersection
for match in matches_1:
    if match in matches_2:
        print(f"{match} is in both files")
```

Prints

```
GCA_000739415.1 is in both files
GCA_000739415.1 is in both files
```

But I would recommend:

```
# The preferred method for intersection, where order is not important
matches = list(set(matches_1) & set(matches_2))
```

Which saves as:

```
['GCA_000739415.1']
```

---

Note the regex matches in a form of `GX[A or F]_[number; digit >= 1].[number; digit >= 1]`. Let me know if this is not what you are after

> [Regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/MY45I6/1)

---

#### Edit

I believe you are after the [symmetric difference of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) for files 1 and 2. Which is a fancy way of saying "things in A & B, that are not in both"

Which can be done with literation:

```py
# Iteration
# A set has no duplicates, and is unordered
sym_dif = set()
for match in matches_1:
    if match not in matches_2:
        sym_dif.add(match)
```

```
>>> list(sym_dif)
['GCF_001297745.1', 'GCA_001297745.1']
```

I think your mistake was not using a set, you should't have any duplicates, and using `matches_1 == matches_2`. The lists won't be the same. You should check if it is `not in` the other set.

Or using this set notation which is the preferred method:

```
>>> list(set(matches_1).symmetric_difference(set(matches_2)))
['GCF_001297745.1', 'GCA_001297745.1']
```

Comment: I have a question: I want to search which patterns are in one file, only. So I modified your script for this: `for match in matches_1:
    if match not in matches_2:
        print(f"{match} is in both files")` This prints all the patterns when I expect to print only a few ones, any idea why?

Comment: Would you kindy append this example (a bit of your file text) to your question, with the actual and expected output please?

Answer (score 1):

As I am looking at these files, it is a data frame from the txt file link you shared.
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/README_assembly_summary.txt

> ```
> The assembly_summary.txt files have 22 tab-delimited columns. 
> Header rows begin with '#".
> ```

**A better approach would start would be to open the files as tab-separated pandas data frames and apply a function to split and replace all the F with A, and then merge the two files or simply use the `is in` command to get the indices of the common elements.** Here is the code:

> Notebook with rationale and algorithm, with comments -

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jJYnDpMVCt1spRsUek7RqlMnC_2O92sq?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd
url1="https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/assembly_summary_genbank.txt"
url2 = "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/assembly_summary_refseq.txt"
df1=pd.read_csv(url1,sep='\t',low_memory=False)
df2=pd.read_csv(url2,sep='\t',low_memory=False)
def replaceFs(string_test):
  list_words = list(string_test)
  list_words[2]='A'
  return_string = ''.join(list_words)
  return return_string
def table_reform(unformed_df):
  unformed_df = unformed_df.reset_index()
  unformed_df = unformed_df.rename(columns=unformed_df.iloc[0])
  reformed_df = unformed_df[1:]
  return reformed_df
df1 = table_reform(df1)
df2 = table_reform(df2)
df2['# assembly_accession'] = df2['# assembly_accession'].apply(replaceFs)
df_combine = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['# assembly_accession'],how='inner') 
df_combine
```

Which shows a huge data frame 254000 rows × 45 columns

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/paritoshk/7eed427943399237c14b911adfee4428.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps! My personal view from the CS angle is that double loops with Regex are much slower on such large datasets vs Pandas algorithms.